# Google map won't display on android realdevice(2.3) but display on emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I develop an android application for tracking Nearest ATMs.Map was displayed on *Android emulator 2.3.3(API 10) and android 4.3(API 18)*. And in Emulator the user current location not displayed. The Target of emulators are not Google APIs. But map not Displayed on real device android 2.3.6 (Gingerbread). How to install App to real device? just copy to SD card and install is enough for this app? so please help me.Thanks in advance.

My Files:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.atmtracker;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.CancelableCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity implements LocationListener{

private static final long MIN_TIME = 400;
private static final float MIN_DISTANCE = 1000;
private GoogleMap map;
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
  static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
  private LocationManager locationmanager;
  private String provider;
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
try
{
    initailizemap();

}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
private void initailizemap() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(map==null)
    {
        map=((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if(map==null)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "don't display map", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.setMapType(map.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
            map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
             Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
                        .title("Hamburg"));
                    Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(KIEL)
                        .title("Kiel")
                        .snippet("Kiel is cool")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG,15));

            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

             locationmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
                locationmanager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, this);
            // Getting the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Getting Current Location
            try
            {

                Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            if(location!=null){
            // Getting latitude of the current location
                Log.i("Loc","GEt location");
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                Log.i("Lat","GEt lat");
            // Getting longitude of the current location
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            Log.i("Lng","GEt lang");
            // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            String loc=String.valueOf(latLng);
            Log.i("latlng",loc);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),loc ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
           map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));
           map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10));
           LatLng    myPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
           map.setTrafficEnabled(true);

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(myPosition).title("Start").snippet("kvp").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
            }
            else
            {
                Log.i("loc","Location is null");
                Toast.makeText(this, "location is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
               Log.i("Loc","don't get location");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "don't get Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }
        }
}
    }
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    initailizemap();
}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Location location = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    locationmanager.removeUpdates(this);
}
@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


}
    }
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.atmtracker"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
>
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyBTjnSiMMWGtQAYln6NUNMHjFQ4l5AWrzA"/> 

<permission 
    android:name="com.example.atmtracker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.atmtracker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission" />
<!-- show current location -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature 
    android:glEsVersion="0x00010000"
    android:required="true"/>        

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="10" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"


    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.atmtracker.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="API_KEY_VALUE"/> 
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

activitymian.xml::

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">
<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

logcat errors:
  **Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.gsf.gservices**

**correct Code:**
After I changed This code i got map on My device.
No need to put API_key in 2 places. just place it APPLICATION tag.
when Release the app to public remove " android:debuggable="true" " line from manifest file.
use **com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES** permission instead of **com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission** in manifest file.
No change in Main Activity
some changes in manifest file

```
    <permission 
        android:name="com.example.atmtracker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"
        />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.atmtracker.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <!-- show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature 
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>        

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.atmtracker.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


 <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="API_KEY"/> 
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
  android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you check if the device has Google Play Services installed? Also, check if an update is available.

Comment: I install the Google play services to emulator by get backup from realdevice

Comment: I don't know if your problem is caused by this, but just try to use the `class` attribute instead of `android:name` (as u can see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html)

Comment: i change to class but map won't show on real device.but it was displayed on emulator perfectly. is any procedure for install the app to device?please help me?